# C Program isn't Stopping at Breakpoints During Debug For Visual Studio Code

Tags: c, debugging, visual-studio-code, breakpoints

So, basically I have a breakpoint but the debugger isn't stopping at the breakpoint.
To compile I am using

```
gcc -g balance1.c -o ./test
```

The program takes in input and outputs fine it's just that I am explicitly putting a breakpoint and it isn't stopping no yellow line or anything. Granted it's the first time I've coded with C or used the debugger in any capacity so, thanks! Below is the launch.json file.

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(Windows) Launch",
            "type": "cppvsdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/balance1.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "justMyCode": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "console": "externalTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: which VSCode extensions are you using for that?

Comment: follow the instructions on the doc page to the letter, otherwise you get some strange results from `gdb`

Comment: THANKS. So I read the documentation and got it to work. For future reference, the fix for me was that I was debugging in the Windows and not the GDB and I was using minGW and not the GW that was recommended by the C/C++ extension but it worked anyways. In fact I couldn't get the mingw64 working for me but it's okay.